# Configure gvim for python

Tags: python, gvim

I changed from Arch to Ubuntu. I installed gvim via apt-get, but it used to auto indent a tablength of 4 spaces after keywords in python if working in .py files. This is gone now. I there a way to get it back?

Comment: changed from arch to ubuntu? well how can this even happen

Comment: Read `man gvim`, and look at the document files listed therin.

Comment: Well I ran Manjaro before. But this distribution is not so common, so I just said Arch. Is this so false?